# Call data from list items

Tags: javascript, xml

it's my first time writing here.
    i have a basic level in javascript.any help would be appreciated!

```
the html code

<li>
<b>stathmoi: </b><span id="Title"></span><br/>
<b>thermokrasia: </b><span id="Temp"></span><br/>
<b>Elevation: </b><span id="Elevation"></span><br/>
</li><hr/>
<li>
<b>stathmoi: </b><span id="Title"></span><br/>
<b>thermokrasia: </b><span id="Temp"></span><br/>
<b>Elevation: </b><span id="Elevation"></span><br/>
</li><hr/>
<li>
<b>stathmoi: </b><span id="Title"></span><br/>
<b>thermokrasia: </b><span id="Temp"></span><br/>
<b>Elevation: </b><span id="Elevation"></span><br/>
</li><hr/>
<li>
<b>stathmoi: </b><span id="Title"></span><br/>
<b>thermokrasia: </b><span id="Temp"></span><br/>
<b>Elevation: </b><span id="Elevation"></span><br/>
</li><hr/>

the js code


    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
      }   
    else  
      {// code for IE6, IE5  
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","domparser.xml",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    //document.getElementsByTagName('li');  
    document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML=  
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
    document.getElementById("Temp").innerHTML=  
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
    document.getElementById("Elevation").innerHTML=  
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("elevation")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
    //document.getElementById("Title").innerHTML=  
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
    //document.getElementById("Temp").innerHTML=  
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;  
    //document.getElementById("Elevation").innerHTML=  
    xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("elevation")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

**Here is the xml code** - domparser.xml

```
<channel>    
<item>    
<title>kalimnos</title>    
<temp>50</temp>    
<elevation>650m</elevation>    
</item>    
<item>    
<title>kerkira</title>    
<temp>30</temp>    
<elevation>1650m</elevation>    
</item>    
<item>    
<title>iraklio</title>    
<temp>50</temp>    
<elevation>50m</elevation>    
</item>    
<item>    
<title>xania</title>    
<temp>30</temp>    
<elevation>150m</elevation>    
</item>    
</channel>
```

when the html file runs display only the data of the first "item" of the xml file.
i am trying to display all the list items with different "item" of the xml every time.

for example in the 1st list item :
stathmoi: kalimnos
thermokrasia: 50
Elevation: 650m

for example in the 2nd list item :
stathmoi: kerkira
thermokrasia: 30
Elevation: 1650m

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different IDs for the spans.

```
<li>
<b>stathmoi: </b><span id="Title"></span><br/>
<b>thermokrasia: </b><span id="Temp"></span><br/>
<b>Elevation: </b><span id="Elevation"></span><br/>
</li><hr/>
<li>
<b>stathmoi: </b><span id="Title1"></span><br/>
<b>thermokrasia: </b><span id="Temp1"></span><br/>
<b>Elevation: </b><span id="Elevation1"></span><br/>
</li><hr/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From an 'old school' javascript approach, you could do the below.

Once you get the data, you can loop through, creating your structure as you go. This means that the structure will be as large or as small as the data you receive.

**In the header**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("my-listview");

  // replace 'i<10' with 'i<xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title").length' 
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    // Left 1
    var divLeft1 = document.createElement("div");
    divLeft1.className = "Left1";
    li.appendChild(divLeft1);
    var div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.id = "Title"+i
    div2.innerHTML = div2.id; //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    divLeft1.appendChild(div2);

    // Left 2
    var divLeft2 = document.createElement("div");
    divLeft2.className = "Left2";
    li.appendChild(divLeft2);
    var div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.id = "Temp"+i
    div3.innerHTML = div3.id; //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("temp")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    divLeft2.appendChild(div3);
    var div4 = document.createElement("div");
    div4.id = "Elevation"+i
    div4.innerHTML = div4.id; //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("elevation")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    divLeft2.appendChild(div4);

    // Right1
    var divRight1 = document.createElement("div");
    divRight1.className = "Right1";
    li.appendChild(divRight1);
    var div5 = document.createElement("div");
    div5.id = "Beaufort"+i
    div5.innerHTML = div5.id;  //xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("beaufort")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    divRight1.appendChild(div5);

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
};
```

When the page has finished loading, this will insert the structure into your 'ul':

You can find more on 'createElement' at W3Schools, but any standard tag can be created this way.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp